# Automatically change access level on a user in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, access-levels

Is there a way to setup an automatic change of access level in Azure DevOps after a specific number of days?
E.g. Setup a rule that the access level is automatically changed from "Basic + Test Plans" to "Basic" after 30 days.

Best regards

Lillian Hjelmstad

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to implement this requirement.

1. Use this Reset API: [User Entitlements - Get User Entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get a paged set of user entitlements, and then find the `id` of target user.
2. Use this Rest API: [User Entitlements - Update User Entitlement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/update%20user%20entitlement?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to update target user's access level. And the following request body(`Content-Type: application/json-patch+json`) will change the access level to Basic.

```
[
    {
        "from":"",
        "op":2,
        "path":"/accessLevel",
        "value":{
            "accountLicenseType":2,
            "licensingSource":1
        }
    }
]
```

3. To success to call this API, you should authenticate with identity as [a Project Collection Administrator or an organization Owner.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/lookup-organization-owner-admin?view=azure-devops) You could create a PAT with full access.
4. Create a yaml pipeline to run this API and [set scheduled triggers using cron syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: Hi Lillian Hjelmstad, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.